# LiipImagineBundle / Retina

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

Is it possible to somehow configure bundle to generate images also for retina display, like @2x?

Or can someone give me an advice how to deal with retina?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/123#issuecomment-63602688) by [nahakiole](https://github.com/nahakiole), there are 2 solutions for this:

> You can either use the picture element which would provide the syntax
>   to declare multiple sources for an image.
>   http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-picture-element

> The other method which we've tried was, if you can guarantee that the
>   image exists, to use a modified version of the retina.js which adds
>   _retina to the filter name and checks if a image with this name exists.

[Modified version of retina.js](https://gist.github.com/nahakiole/d02d1270cc05348adfd6) by [nahakiole](https://gist.github.com/nahakiole):

```html
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* RETINA.JS
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
(function () {

    var regex = /(media\/cache\/filter_[A-Z]+)/i //Added this
    function t(e) {
        this.path = e;
        var t = this.path.split("."),
            n = t.slice(0, t.length - 1).join("."),
            r = t[t.length - 1];
        this.at_2x_path = (n + '.' + r).replace(regex, '$1_retina') //Changed that
    }
    function n(e) {
        this.el = e, this.path = new t(this.el.getAttribute("src"));
        var n = this;
        this.path.check_2x_variant(function (e) {
            e && n.swap()
        })
    }
    var e = typeof exports == "undefined" ? window : exports;
    e.RetinaImagePath = t, t.confirmed_paths = [], t.prototype.is_external = function () {
        return !!this.path.match(/^https?\:/i) && !this.path.match("//" + document.domain)
    }, t.prototype.check_2x_variant = function (e) {
        var n, r = this;
        if (this.is_external()) return e(!1);
        if (this.at_2x_path in t.confirmed_paths) return e(!0);
        n = new XMLHttpRequest, n.open("HEAD", this.at_2x_path), n.onreadystatechange = function () {
            return n.readyState != 4 ? e(!1) : n.status >= 200 && n.status <= 399 ? (t.confirmed_paths.push(r.at_2x_path), e(!0)) : e(!1)
        }, n.send()
    }, e.RetinaImage = n, n.prototype.swap = function (e) {
        function n() {
            t.el.complete ? (t.el.setAttribute("width", t.el.offsetWidth), t.el.setAttribute("height", t.el.offsetHeight), t.el.setAttribute("src", e)) : setTimeout(n, 5)
        }
        typeof e == "undefined" && (e = this.path.at_2x_path);
        var t = this;
        n()
    }, e.devicePixelRatio > 1 && (window.onload = function () {
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
            t = [],
            r, i;
        for (r = 0; r < e.length; r++) i = e[r], t.push(new n(i))
    })
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, but link does not exist(404)

Comment: @kironet I've replaced the broken picture link ;)

Comment: This link explains <html> element.

Comment: Grr... fixed! Was a google link, replaced by the correct one.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, can you explain how to work with retina.js and liipimagine? 
I imported retina.js, tried to add  data-rjs, but nothing changed.

Comment: In console I se this error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL
    at XMLHttpRequest.open (http://domain.com:233:7990)
    at t.check_2x_variant (http://domain.com/js/main_retina_2.js:28:35)
    at new n (http://domain.com/js/main_retina_2.js:17:19)
    at e.devicePixelRatio.window.onload (http:/domain.com/js/main_retina_2.js:42:57)`